# Позиционирование кнопок

Tags: css, html5

[image]Проблема с позиционированием кнопок, почему улетают две вниз? Как выровнять?

```css
.read-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#read {
  width: 272px;
  height: 311px;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
  margin: 52px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #e5e6e6;
}

.img_read {
  margin-top: 49px;
}

.title_read {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #7f8c8c;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.text_read {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #777777;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 0;
}

.read_more {
  background-color: #76c7c0;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 13px;
  width: 201px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #62b9b0;
  margin-left: 35.5px;
  margin-top: 28px;
}

.read_more a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="read-wrap">
      <div id="read">
        <div class="img_read"><img src="img/ok.png" alt=""></div>
        <div class="title_read">
          Suspendisse
        </div>
        <div class="text_read">
          <p>Quisque id tellus quis risus vehicula<br/>vehicula ut turpis. In eros nulla, placerat<br/>vitae at, vehicula ut nunc. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="read_more"><a href="#">read more</div>
     
    </a>
        </div>
        <div id="read">
          <div class="img_read"><img src="img/key.png" alt=""></div>
          <div class="title_read">
            Maecenas
          </div>
          <div class="text_read">
            <p>Ut eleifend libero sed neque rhoncus<br/>consequat. Maecenas tincidunt, augue<br/>et rutrum condimentum, libero lectus<br/>mattis orci, ut commodo.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="read_more"><a href="#">read more</div>
    </a>
          </div>
          <div id="read">
            <div class="img_read"><img src="img/flag.png" alt=""></div>
            <div class="title_read">
              Aliquam
            </div>
            <div class="text_read">
              <p>Vivamus eget ante bibendum arc<br/>vehicula ultricies. Integer venenatis<br/>mattis nisl, vitae pulvinar dui tempor<br/>non. </p>
            </div>
            <div class="read_more"><a href="#">read more</div>
     
    </a>
            </div>
            <div id="read">
              <div class="img_read"><img src="img/bottle.png" alt=""></div>
              <div class="title_read">
                Habitasse
              </div>
              <div class="text_read">
                <p>Astehicula ultricies. Integer venenatis<br/>mattis nisl, vitae pulvinar dui tempor<br/>non. </p>
              </div>
              <div class="read_more"><a href="#">read more</div>
     
    </a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код?

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

уберите высоту **height: 311px;** у блоком #read

вместо него лучше задать высоту у блока текста **.text_read**

Ну и id должен быть уникальным, вместо #read - используйте класс **.read**

Comment: Благодарю, всё сработало